# Не передается значение во всплывающее окно

Tags: javascript, css

Есть несколько таких блоков, при нажатии на кнопку заказать во всплывающее окно должно передаваться значение тега h2, но этого не происходит, и класс active не присваивается.

```js
    $(".buys").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // убираем класс active
        $(".product-h.active").removeClass("active");
        // добавляем класс active для блока внутри которого находится нажимаемый buys
        $(this).closest(".product-h").addClass("active");  
    });
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  if ($(".product-h").hasClass("active")) {
    var title= $(".product-h.active.product-meta h2").text();
    $(".title").text('Название' + title);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-meta">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Vending Crema e Aroma</h2>
            <div class="case-objarka">
                <h6>Вкусовые ноты</h6>

                <ul class="vkus">
                    <li class="vcus-citrus">Цитрусовый</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="case-objarka">
                <h6>Обжарка</h6>

                <p><span class="objarka-srednyay">средняя</span></p>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="case-objarka">
                <h6>Состав</h6>
                <div сlass="case-smesi">
                </div>
                <ul class="sostav">

                    <li сlass="case-arabika">
                        <div class="arabika-n arabik-a_30"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; 30%</div>
                        <div class="arabika-t">арабика </div>
                    </li>

                    <li сlass="case-robusta">
                        <div class="robusta-n robusta-r_70"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; 70%</div>
                        <div class="robusta-t">робуста</div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <div class="line"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
                <div class="product-meta">
                    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
                        <p>От 6 пачек в заказе. Отправим одну пачку на пробу по оптовой цене.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">390&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
</a><a class="button product_type_external" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="color: white;">Заказать</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите проверку

```
if ($(".product-h").hasClass("active")) {
```

Comment: Но таких блоков несколько, и класс active необходим, и он почему-то не добавляется

Comment: @Alexander Я подозреваю, что блок с обоими классами - `product-h` и `active` - только один.

Comment: а где этот .product-h должен-то быть? в примере его нигде нету.